# OneToMany inserindo um novo registro?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estou tentando criar um relacionamento OneToMany entre 2 classes "Usuario e Corretora" onde 1 Usuario tem muitas Corretoras.
O problema é quando eu adiciono uma nova Corretora um novo Usuario é criado e eu não sei pq isso acontece

Como resolver isso?

**Usuario**

```
public class Usuario
{         
    public long id { get; set; }

    public String nome { get; set; }    

    public IList<Corretora> corretoras { get; set; }
}
```

**Corretora**

```
public class Corretora
{        
    public long id { get; set; }

    public String nome { get; set; }    

    public Usuario usuario { get; set; }
}
```

**UsuarioMap**

```
public class UsuarioMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Usuario>
{
    public UsuarioMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Usuarios");
        this.HasKey<long>(u => u.id);
        this.Property(u => u.id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        this.Property(u => u.nome).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);

        //um usuario tem muitas corretoras
        HasMany(u => u.corretoras).WithRequired(c => c.usuario);
     }
 }
```

**CorretoraMap**

```
public class CorretoraMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Corretora>
{    
    public CorretoraMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("Corretoras");
        this.HasKey<long>(c => c.id);
        this.Property(c => c.id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        this.Property(c => c.nome).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);       

        HasRequired(u => u.usuario).WithMany(c => c.corretoras);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Não ficou claro para mim o que você quer dizer com "quando eu *adiciono* uma nova Corretora"... mas tente o seguinte: comente a linha `HasRequired(u => u.usuario).WithMany(c => c.corretoras);` de CorretoraMap e reteste.

Comment: Se possível posta o trecho em que está preenchendo a entidade "Corretora" antes de inserir no BD.

Comment: Cade o código da inserção, que demonstra a criação do usuário?